# How to fix the [ERROR] Helper - Failed to get registered user: Jim with error: TypeError: client.loadFromConfig is not a function

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

> to solve the bug when i running hyperledger fabrics , balance
>   transfer by using the command in the bash script using the commands
>   ./runApp.sh    ./tesAPIs.sh 
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------------ then getting the error: [2019-04-04    16:20:42.432] [ERROR] Helper -
>   Failed to get registered user: Jim    with error: TypeError:
>   client.loadFromConfig is not a function    [2019-04-04 16:20:42.432]
>   [ERROR] Helper - Failed to get registered    user: Jim with error:
>   TypeError: client.loadFromConfig is not a    function
>   ----------------------------------------------------------------------------  tried with the hyperledger-fabric version 1.2.0 and
>   hyperledger-fabric version 1.4.0 , both times getting the same error
>   when i am running   ./runApp.sh   ./tesAPIs.sh   when i am running
>   from  hyperledger fabric from balance transfer.  [ERROR] Helper -
>   Failed to get registered user: Jim with error:     TypeError:
>   client.loadFromConfig is not a function   this error should  be
>   removed.

Comment: suggest to follow the README instructions here -> https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/release-1.4/balance-transfer/README.md (eg Option 1 in that doc ?)

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to fix this bug.
The thing is that in file helper.js in `app` folder, on the line 44 `await` is missing.

You can look at this line

`let client = hfc.loadFromConfig(hfc.getConfigSetting('network'+config));`

And when you log `client` you will see that there is a promise. 
So you need just to add `await` before hfc.loadFromConfig and client will be a valid object with `loadFromConfig` function.